# Putting Mysql results into a multidimensional php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a mysql table which I want to have it as a PHP array. Suppose we have a field call `id` and another field called `name`. As there may be not one result in the table I want something like `$result[0]['id']` to point the first result's id.
I thought of this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_name
                                 WHERE dependence = 0");
            $rows = array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $rows = $row;
            }
            echo $rows[0]['name'];
```

But it doesn't work!!! Would you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_name
                             WHERE dependence = 0");
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
     $i=0;
     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
         $rows[$i] = $row['id'];
         $rows[$i] = $row['name']; 
      $i++;  
     }
```

Comment: Solution is fine, however, you don't even need $i and since $row is a named array, you can just add the row to the new array..

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to give column name

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['colname'];//fill inside which column you need $row['colname']
 }
```